# Обработка клика мышки по графику в Matplotlib

Tags: python, python-3.x, button, matplotlib, toolbar

Мне нужно, что бы при нажатии на `plot` у меня ставилась точка. 
Есть вот такой код, все работает, но тут программа реагирует на абсолютно любой клик по графику, даже когда мы, например, зумим график.

Как это исправить?

```
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
import numpy
from matplotlib.widgets import Button

if __name__ == "__main__":
    x_pts = []
    y_pts = []

    fig, ax = plt.subplots()

    #line, = ax.plot(x_pts, y_pts, marker="o")

    scale_factor = 5
    xmin, xmax = -100, 100
    ymin, ymax = -100, 100
    plt.xlim(xmin * scale_factor, xmax * scale_factor)
    plt.ylim(ymin * scale_factor, ymax * scale_factor)


    def onpick(event):
        m_x, m_y = event.x, event.y
        x, y = ax.transData.inverted().transform([m_x, m_y])
        x_pts.append(x)
        y_pts.append(y)
        ax.plot(x, y, 'ro')
        fig.canvas.draw()


    fig.canvas.mpl_connect('button_press_event', onpick)

    plt.show()
```

Answer (score 1):

Попробуйте так

```
import numpy
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.widgets import Button


if __name__ == "__main__":
    x_pts = []
    y_pts = []
    fig, ax = plt.subplots()
    scale_factor = 5
    xmin, xmax = -100, 100
    ymin, ymax = -100, 100
    plt.xlim(xmin * scale_factor, xmax * scale_factor)
    plt.ylim(ymin * scale_factor, ymax * scale_factor)
    
    def onpick(event):
        tb = plt.get_current_fig_manager().toolbar                         # +++ 
        print(repr(tb.mode),bool(tb.mode) )                                # +++ 
        if not tb.mode:                                                    # +++ 
            m_x, m_y = event.x, event.y
            x, y = ax.transData.inverted().transform([m_x, m_y])
            x_pts.append(x)
            y_pts.append(y)
            ax.plot(x, y, 'ro')
            fig.canvas.draw()
  
    fig.canvas.mpl_connect('button_press_event', onpick)
    plt.show()
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: @user435351 что не так ?